# How do I get rid of this borders for the <Link>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't get why the links are surrounded by the borders when I use them in the table.

The links outside the table are looking just fine and don't have a border.

The border is now gone but the borders for the table are still missing.
Why is this happening?

```
<tr key={post.id} id={post.id}>
    <Link to = "/login" 
          style={{ color: '#FFF', textDecoration: "none", outline: 'none', fontSize: 1}}
          >
        <td style={{border:0}}>{post.name}</td>
    </Link>
    <td>{post.symbol}</td>
    <td>{post.industry}</td>
</tr>
```

Links Inside the Table:
[image: Links inside the table:]

Links outside the table:
[image: Links outside the table:]

Comment: try to use `textDecoration: "none !important"` , it may fix that

Answer (score 0):

Try `border : 0` in the `style` of the Link

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is not really with the link itself, the borders for the table is gone...

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer I will re-post a question

Comment: can you share the code with codeshare or any other alternatives please ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `border : 0` on the `<td>` tag.